# Would an Amulet of Proof against Detection and Location work against deities searching for someone?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, religions-and-deities

Would an *amulet of proof against detection and location* work against a deity that was trying to find someone?

Answer (score 6):

#### Barring any divine abilities not defined in the rules, the amulet would protect you.

All the deities whose stats are defined in D&D have, at best, no special remote sensing ability. This limits them to their physical sight, which is generally limited to truesight 120 ft, and ordinary divination magic, only the latter of which which is blocked by the amulet of proof against detection and location (DMG p.150):

> While wearing this amulet, you are hidden from **divination magic**. You can't be targeted by such magic or perceived through **magical scrying sensors**.

As per DMG p.11, there are five categories of deities:

- **Greater deities** are described as removed from mortal affairs, and beyond mortal understanding. Whether they can see you is not defined in D&D 5th edition rules, and potentially impossible for anyone within the D&D world to determine.
- **Lesser deities** have physical bodies and physically live on a plane somewhere. This appears to meet the depiction of Tiamat, whose statblock in *Rise of Tiamat* has truesight 120ft and darkvision 240ft, but no remote sensing ability.
- **Titans**, the creations of deities, have direct stats in D&D. This includes the empyrean (Monster Manual p.130), the offspring of deities, whose senses are defined as truesight 120ft. They likewise have no remote sensing or ability to ignore magic amulets.
- **Demigods**, the offspring of a deity and a mortal, are weaker than titans. It's very unlikely that they would have remote sensing.
- **Vestiges** are gods who are dead for all practical purposes, and it's doubtful that they can even use divination magic.

In earlier editions of D&D, particularly D&D 3e, deities did indeed have remote sensing abilities. It's possible that a deity has either the ability to penetrate the protection offered by a magic item (magic items created by deities can ignore *antimagic field*, for example), or a remote sensing power, but this is not defined anywhere in D&D 5th edition rules.

Answer (score 3):

If the deity in question was using divination magic to find the person wearing an [*amulet of proof against detection and location*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/amulet-of-proof-against-detection-and-location), then yes.

> While wearing this amulet, you are hidden from divination magic. You can't be targeted by such magic or perceived through magical scrying sensors.

If the deity were employing all of their followers to search for the particular person, then it likely wouldn't since that is not using magic.

Keep in mind that deities are not always all-knowing and all-powerful beings; they are beings that exist in one plane of existence that are powerful enough to influence another plane of existence or the beings therein. They still rely on magic much the same as others in the multiverse.

Ultimately it would be up to DM discretion as to how a deity would acquire such knowledge, however.